# Pycharm manage.py autocomplete error

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) `1.10` and [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) `2016.2`.

In every Django project, `manage.py` commands work correctly but autocomplete gives the following error:

```
Failed to get real commands on module "projects_name" python died with code 1
File opt/Pycharm/helpers/.../jb_manage_tasks_provider.py
File opt/pycharm/helpers.../parser.py
File my virtual env folder/lib/python3.5/site packages/django/core/management/base.py
AttributeError  Command object has no attribute 'args'
```

Reinstalling Pycharm did not help.

Answer (score 6):

You can use helper from community edition which support django 1.10+
Replace file 
JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2\helpers\pycharm\django_manage_commands_provider_parser\parser.py

with [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pycharm/django_manage_commands_provider/_parser/parser.py)

Comment: this gives me `TypeError: report_data() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Had a similar issue, resolved by modifying the file "_jb_manage_tasks_provider.py" in helpers\pycharm - just go to the line #22 and modify the code to smth like "parser.report_data(dumper, [])" - the thing is that it was missing "commands_to_skip" argument. After passing empty list it all work just fine for me, I don't get any error and hints are working again for manage.py task.

Answer (score 2):

i've been using django 1.10 and pycharm not supporting it yet.
Downgraded to 1.9.8 and now autocompletion works without errors